# Secure socket vs data encryption

Tags: sockets, security, encryption, network-programming

I have a project where data sent between two peers needs to be encrypted. I dont need to authenticate the server or the client , I just need my data to be unreadable on the network.

I have two options:

**1- Secure socket**
- Open a secure socket
- Write clear data

**2- Socket**
- Open a socket
- Encrypt data
- Write encrypted data

Is there a performance benefit in using a secure socket instead of "normal" socket in which I write encrypted data? (let's say i'm using the same cipher in both case)

Comment: Create prototypes of both alternatives, and benchmark?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel unless you somehow know `TLS 1.2` is broken and `1.3` will not be released unless there is a backdoor? performance difference would not be significant and most likely your own implementation would not beat the built-in implementation.

Comment: There is no reason to expect any performance difference, though the first comment of @Someprogrammerdude applies. Most programmers' home-grown encryption protocols will be buggier and insecure compared to something like TLS, even if you use secure algorithms. Security protocols are more than just the sum of their algorithms.

Comment: Data doesn't have a multiple "datas", just like there no milks. There are however coffees and I'm off to get one.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes and Spaghetti is plural (in Italian), corrected post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference with regards to speed when it comes to the algorithms used. In general you'd need authenticity, integrity and authenticity of messages in a *transport protocol*. Generally after the initial handshake this is performed by symmetric algorithms in a rather efficient manner.

Creating your own transport protocol is so fraught with danger that the chance of creating and implementing a secure protocol by a novice is about zero. *For instance*, if you don't know about plaintext or padding oracle attacks then you may loose confidentiality of the message, basically leaving you with messages without any protection.

So check the fastest TLS 1.2 or 1.3 ciphersuites and use that. You may want to check what Google has introduced to TLS; they've really focussed on speed and security.

Answer (score 1):

(Note that a secure socket without authentication allows a man in the middle (MITM) to intercept and thus see in the clear your data.)

A secure socket will take longer to establish, then taken about the same to encrypt. So performance wise, if you have a pre-shared symmetric encryption key, you would benefit a from skipping the ssl/tls handshake and go directly to tcp socket. That would show as a big speedup for numerous short connections, in particular if they were not using sslcontext and session resumption (lots of JSSE jargon, I know, but I keep it obscure because this you know or you don't, here is not the place).

However, if you don't have a pre-shared key, the whole handshake is really something you shouldn't avoid.

Comment: I don't get it. My answer is self contained.

Comment: OK, fine, but your initial answer started with "That being said" without linking to any source. As that's now fixed the problem is solved. That's a good point about session resumption.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to what I said about MITM.