# AJAX request ECHO security issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using an AJAX request from a JS file to query a server. Using PHP for server side code.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once 'dbconfig.php';


if ($_POST) {

    $meeting = new \App\Scoreboard\ MEETINGS($DB_con);

    $response = $meeting->get_meeting();

} else {
    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    $response['message'] = 'Error.';
}


echo json_encode($response);
```

But the response is in the form echo json_encode($response) - which I can see unencoded in the Network tab of Chrome Developer tools.

This defeats the purpose for accessing the secret api key.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'inc/src/ajax.get-meeting.php',
        data: {name: "today"},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var API_SECRET = data.meeting;              

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error !');
        }

    });
```

What should I do instead?

Comment: Client calls server -> server makes calls using the key -> server returns response -> client uses response.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking, but I think you are concerned about sensitive data being sent over the network?  That is why you use https.

Comment: Sorry I was being dumb - the reason the sensitive data was exposed was because it was not hashed/encrypted. I have a function now that properly encrypts the data that needs to be sent. Now the problem is just to understand how to use the FETCH command from my javascript function to get at it.

Comment: I think you are still misunderstanding the problem.  Data sent between client/server does not need to be encrypted at application level.  Your password is not encrypted by Javascript or the browser before being sent to your bank, https looks after that at the network layer. Likewise any secret your server sends the the client does not need to be encrypted by your application to be kept safe - that's what https is *for*. Over an https connection, you can still see your unencrypted response in the browser, and that's OK - nobody else can, it is an encrypted connection between client/server.

Comment: Don't take my word for it though, here are some relevant questions on SE sites: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76764/encrypt-data-going-through-an-encrypted-connection

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159158/does-it-still-make-sense-to-encrypt-data-over-ssl

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159158/does-it-still-make-sense-to-encrypt-data-over-ssl

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003246/secure-socket-vs-data-encryption

Comment: Well it was for integrating Zoom on a web browser - and the SDK requires a signature generated with a secret API key which you don't want to be public to any user. But by creating the signature server side with that secret key and only then passing the result to the client, nothing sensitive is revealed. At first I was trying to send that secret key and generate the signature client side in a function.